# Is it possible extend Schrodinger theory in relativistic contexts with naive consideration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, schroedinger-equation, klein-gordon-equation

**Preamble**

Let's consider a generic sinusoidal wave $\Psi (\mathbf{r},t) = A e^{i(\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r} - \omega t + \phi)}$
and let's insert it into Schroedinger equation (please note that $
\nabla^2 \Psi = - k^2 \Psi $ and $
\dot{\Psi} = - i \omega \Psi $
), we can write
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} k^2 + U = \hbar \omega
\end{equation*}
where $k=|\mathbf{k}|$. Using de Broglie relations ($ E = \hbar \omega$ and $ \mathbf{p} = \hbar \mathbf{k}$) we can then obtain classical conservation of energy $\frac{p^2}{2m} + U = E$. This manipulations have sense? Anyway they led to useful Schroedinger equation, so we could be tempted to do something similar in relativistic contexts. Consider this conservation equation (here $E$ is not the total relativistic energy)
\begin{equation*}
E = \sqrt{m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2} - mc^2 + U
\end{equation*}
isolating root, squaring, and doing a similar reasoning, we can obtain an equation that works for zero spin particles (as I said elsewhere, I found this equation in pag 42 of Wachter's *Relativistic Quantum Mechanics* in which $V=U-mc^2$)
\begin{equation*}
c^2 \hbar^2 \nabla^2 \Psi = 
\hbar^2 \ddot{\Psi} + 2i\hbar (U - mc^2) \dot{\Psi} + U (2mc^2 - U) \Psi 
\end{equation*}
Similarly, starting by the weakly and extreme relativistic contexts, with
\begin{equation*}
E = \frac{p^2}{2m} - \frac{p^4}{8 m^3 c^2} + U 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*} 
E = pc + \frac{m^2 c^3}{2p} - mc^2 + U 
\end{equation*}
we obtain respectively (in the stationary case)
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \Psi - \frac{\hbar^4}{8 m^3 c^2} \nabla^4 \Psi + U \Psi = E \Psi 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 c^2 \hbar^4 \nabla^4 \Psi + \left[
(E + mc^2 - U)^2 - m^2 c^4
\right] \hbar^2 \nabla^2 \Psi + \displaystyle \frac{m^4 c^6}{4} \Psi = 0
\end{equation*}
(we exploit $\nabla^4 \Psi = k^4 \Psi$, in the second case we multiply by $p$ and rearrange in this way before squaring $(E + mc^2 - U) p = p^2 c + \frac{m^2 c^3}{2}$).

**Question**

All this manipulations have sense? The last two equations that I wrote works for weakly relativistic and extreme relativistic (very small $m$) zero spin particles respectively? Really we can study the first order relativistic correction for zero spin particles adding $ - \frac{\hbar^4}{8 m^3 c^2} \nabla^4 $ to $\widehat{H}$? If yes, how consider spin effects too?

Comment: What's the ground state?

Comment: what do you mean? U is a generic potential we cannot speak about ground states.

Comment: The problem with these formal operations is that $U$ itself is a non-relativistic concept, so most that can be hoped for is a bit of an improvement of the non-relativistic theory. In relativistic electrodynamics, potential energy is not sufficient to describe interaction of charged particles. Maxwell's equations and fields take its place.

Comment: I mean... is there a ground state?

Comment: @CuriousOne Applying this idea to infinite spherical hole, we obtain this quantization of energy:
$$
E = \sqrt{ (m c^2)^2 + \left( \frac{n \pi \hbar c}{a} \right)^2 } - mc^2 \qquad \qquad n \in \mathbb{N}^+
$$
We have the ground state putting $n=1$.

Comment: @JánLalinský Sometimes in relativity physicist works with $U$. I don't have at hand, but I'm sure that Landau wrote $E = \sqrt{m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2} - mc^2 + U$ studying precession of Bohr orbits (I suppose Sommerfeld himself used $U$). But actually it is a weakly relativistic context  (in addition, it is a primitive model). I'll reflect upon what you wrote.

Comment: @CuriousOne I applied this ideas to hydrogen atom  finding that, if $-2mc^2 < E < 0$, $R$ (radial part of $\Psi$) obey to $$
y'' = \left( 1 -\frac{\rho_0}{\rho} + \frac{l(l+1) - \alpha^2}{\rho^2} \right) y $$ where $\alpha = \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 \hbar c}$ is fine structure constant, $y=Rr$,
$$ 
 \rho = \frac{\sqrt{E (E + 2mc^2)}}{i \hbar c} r $$
and
$$ \rho_0 = \frac{2 \alpha (E + mc^2)}{\sqrt{-E(E + 2 mc^2)}} $$ If $c \to \infty$ it becames 4.56 Griffiths. I didn't solve the differential equations, but surely this potential too (like many other simpler) admits a ground state.

Comment: Thanks for the detail! I was wondering if one could extract some information about the weakly relativistic case from this approach. It doesn't look as bad as I expected from some of the comments in qft books which write it down and then immediately move on.

Comment: @CuriousOne I add that when I said "hydrogen atom" I spoken about a physical model (very massive point charge $e$ with another point charge $e$, with only the Coulomb force). I want underline that, in the true hydrogen atom, spin plays a role so we cannot hope to obtain exact relativistic spectral lines with this equation. Maybe in an analog system with zero spin particle, and no other forces than Coulomb one, we can. Furthermore we can use this approach to study successfully zero spin particle in holes (finite hole too, as I wrote elsewhere): we obtain exact solutions.

Comment: Don't worry, I got that. I am fully aware that none of these can replace qft but at least it's a more interesting toy system than I was aware of.